# How to login to a website that uses cookies?

Tags: cookies, python-requests

i have cookie get from website .  how do i log that cookie using requests ?

cookie="sb=Vma2X7D6JF_aBy6ESWdwm-OL; datr=Vma2X2YjSxJ-JzCD368WGfmL; locale=vi_VN; wd=1366x657; c_user=100029745455196;"

how login with requests?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't login with cookie, you need login with credentials: username & password.

If you have logged in with credentials, you MAY use that cookie to bypass login step.